# MySQL access denied from python, but ok from MySQL Workbench

Tags: python, mysql

I have an AWS VPN configured, and a user with limited rights created for me. If the VPN is ON I can access the database from MySQL Workshop, and see details I am allowed to see (few tables). But I cannot access the same database and tables using Python, it says:

> MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user
> 'test_user'@'ip_address_here' (using password: YES)")

I am connecting to the database like this (crashing on conn = MySQLdb.connect):

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(
    database=dbname,
    user=user,
    password=password,
    host=host,
    port=port
)
```

All credentials were copied from Python to MySQL Workshop (so they are correct). Without VPN I can't establish the connection in MySQL Workshop, in python it says there is no host "my_host".

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/130799/accessing-mysql-server-via-vpn-in-python

Comment: @MitchWheat Okay, it wasn't the problem, I've deleted all libs for mysql, and installed from scratch mysql and mysql.connector. I will add answer later, thank you for suggestion

Comment: *"Access denied for user 'test_user'@'**ip_address_here**' (using password: YES)"* - execute `SELECT USER(), CURRENT_USER();` in Workbench (not Workshop) and compare.. also show the output to us.